# ffmpeg to cut subtitle file in sync with the cut video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles, sync

I managed to cut the video and keep subtitle in sync by embedding the subtitles in the video:

```
$ ffmpeg -i sample-mp4-file.mp4 -hide_banner \
    -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt -ss 0:30:00 -t 1:33:31 \
    OutputVideo.mp4
```

I'm wonder if it possible to cut subtitle file in accordance / sync with the cut video, instead of embedding them in the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that `ffmpeg` works on the text based subtitle file just as well:

```sh
$ cat subtitles.srt
1
00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:20,000
This is demo subtitle 1

2
00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:40,000
This is demo subtitle 2

$ ffmpeg -i subtitles.srt -ss 5 -t 60 -y cut.srt

$ cat cut.srt
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:15,000
This is demo subtitle 1

2
00:00:15,000 --> 00:00:35,000
This is demo subtitle 2

$ ffmpeg -i subtitles.srt -ss 10 -t 60 -y cut.srt

$ cat cut.srt
1
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:30,000
This is demo subtitle 2
```

Just exactly as what I wanted.